# Home folder freespace filled up by system updater. No files found

Tags: linux-mint, home

I just installed linux mint 18.3 and ran the system updater (I'm new to linux). Before the updates I had about 6.5GB of freespace on my /home partition (I partition 7.2GB at OS install for /home, 30GB for /, and 4GB for SWAP). **Now I have 160MB left in my /home partition even though I haven't added any files to my home folder.**

**What I've tried so far:**

I checked the /home sub directories through the file system viewer I don't see any files in there. I also looked at the disk usage analyzer and it shows on 296mb of files used, all in "." hidden folders as shown in the screenshot attached below. I also right-clicked on the /home folder and went to properties and it shows only 32kb used and the 8 empty folders that appear at install. I also restarted my computer and noted there there was nothing in the trash bin in Mint.

Could someone shed some light on where all my free space went? This seems weird.

[image: home_diskspace_issue]

Update per comments:

```
noel@noel-pc ~ $ sudo du -hxd1 /home  
16K /home/lost+found  
204M    /home/.ecryptfs  
6.5G    /home/.Trash-0  
6.7G    /home  

noel@noel-pc ~ $ df -h  
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev  
tmpfs                794M  9.5M  785M   2% /run  
/dev/sdc5             28G  6.3G   20G  24% /  
tmpfs                3.9G   83M  3.8G   3% /dev/shm  
tmpfs                5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock  
tmpfs                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/sdc7            7.2G  6.7G  118M  99% /home  
cgmfs                100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs  
tmpfs                794M   52K  794M   1% /run/user/1000  
/home/noel/.Private  7.2G  6.7G  118M  99% /home/noel  
/dev/sde1            1.9T  1.5T  422G  78% /media/noel/My Passport
```

So it looks like the files are in the hidden .trash-0 directory.  How do these files get cleaned normally/nominally since I can't just empty them from the trash bin?  I guess I assumed all deleted files went to the trash bin instead of some hidden directory that requires sudo access to even open for me.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo du -hxd1 /home`, `df -h` and `sudo lsof | grep deleted` to the post, please.

Comment: @muru  there you go